# Open Local network pdf file in webview or any other view

Tags: android, pdf

I am struck on point for showing local network pdf file inside application,

```
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url)
```

It's working fine for public IP urls but when I am trying to load local IP address url like as,

```
http://192.168.x.xxx/xyz/Demo/Testing.pdf
```

Web view gives No preview available message. If any other solution available for this then help me out. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That url should not make any difference except you use an emulator. What i do not understand though is that a webview suddenly can display pdf's.

Comment: `No preview available message`. O i just see that. So you have connection. I think you do not get a pdf from google.

Comment: yes right google unable to detect that IP address. So web view not able to load it.That's problem i am facing.

Comment: `yes right google unable to detect that IP address` ????? google ??? I did not say so. Where are you talking about? Please be exact.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url= url,  If i pass public server url here then web view able to load it.But when i pass local server url then web view not able to load it. for local server case google doc api not working.

Comment: What has your local server to do with google doc api?

Comment: I want to show pdf file inside my application. Normally we load pdf inside webview with help of google doc url i.e. docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=. But this fails when loading pdf from local  (LAN) network. Any other alternative available for this?

Comment: Yes. And why does it fail?

Comment: Because IT not able to recognize 192.168.x.xxx This IP address.

Comment: `IT` ? You have a very confusing subject: `Open Local network pdf file in webview`. The webview is not trying to open a local pdf file. If it was trying to do so you would have code like `webview.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/myfile.pdf")` or `webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.x.xxx/xyz/Demo/Testing.pdf");`. Instead you wonder why google docs cannot find a file on your local lan. That's quite another question and has nothing to do with a webview or android.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72753/discussion-between-chets-and-greenapps).