# PDF not Opening in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to open pdf in webview of android,

I tried using :

webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url)

If url is http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf(this is a sample), its working fine,

but if url is http://192.168.x.xxx:8001/ql/Demo/Demo_Rep_DDForm.pdf its not opening.

Unable to figure out the reason, the above IP is public.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to open PDF documents in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803701/unable-to-open-pdf-documents-in-webview)

Comment: `the above IP is public.`? That looks like a local ip only.

Comment: it is a local ip of my system in which eclipses server is running

Comment: Your comment is not to the point. I expected you to confirm or deny or correct your self.

Comment: Its a local IP @greenapps

Answer (score 1):

A WebView cannot display pdf files.

Comment: its works in server IP but on my local server its not working

Comment: No. A WebView canot display a pdf file. And it is unclear what you mean with a server ip. Please give an example.

Comment: There is no server ip mentioned in your post. Well one. A local one. A local server ip.

Comment: Yes i try to access from local server please tell how i get PDF view from local server

Comment: What is it that you want? I keep saying `A WebView cannot display pdf files.` So even if you get the file from local server you cannot let the webview display it. You need to install a pdf viewer app to display pdf files on an Android device. So do you understand: `A WebView cannot display pdf files.!` ?

Comment: `There is no server ip mentioned in your post. `. And you still did not explain about a server ip. You are not very helpfull for yourself. This takes so much time now just because you dont give decent info.

Comment: If you are not clear with my Question then follow this link  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964850/open-local-network-pdf-file-in-webview-or-any-other-view

Comment: I am new in android o please help to solve this problem

Comment: I will not folow links. Instead you should take the time to give decent answers to my questions and remarks.

Comment: ok don't follow any link . By the way in this link also you give answer related to this but you can't. Its seams you don't have answer you are just wasting my time

Comment: from where you belong's ??

Comment: Can someone answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099883/why-pdf-not-opening-in-iframe-in-chrome-when-switched-to-mobile-device-mode